# Can I travel from Mexico to the Dominican Republic without a passport?

Tags: passports, paperwork, mexican-citizens, dominican-republic

I don't have my Mexican passport. Can I travel to the Dominican Republic with my birth certificate plus my Mexican identification?

Comment: Not on the plane, according to Timatic.

Answer (score 1):

According to a query on the KLM [Traveldoc](https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/) tool, neither your birth certificate nor identification card are accepted documents for entry by the Dominican Republic.